# How to get var value number from script tag in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In a given .html page, I have a script tag like so:

```
<script>
some data 
</script>
<body>
some data
</body>

<script>
var breadcrumbData = {"level":0,"currentCategoryName":"Kebutuhan Dapur","currentCategoryId":"5b85712ca3834cdebbbc4363","parentCategoryId":"","parentCategoryName":null}; 
var pageList = {"totalData":549,"totalPage":12,"pageSize":48,"currentPage":1}; 
var pageSize = 48;
</script>
```

I am trying to get back the totalPage number using soup.

My following code is like so:

```
pattern= re.compile(r'"totalPage":(\d+);', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL) 
scripts =soup.find_all('script', text=pattern)
   if scripts:
   match = pattern.search(scripts.text)
   print(match)
```

A blank list is being returned from the above code, whereas I just need the number 12 to be returned as a number.  Please do help.

Comment: Typo.  Your `totalPage` value is followed by a comma, not a semi-colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways how to extract the number:

#### 1. Using plain `re`

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<script>
some data 
</script>
<body>
some data
</body>

<script>
var breadcrumbData = {"level":0,"currentCategoryName":"Kebutuhan Dapur","currentCategoryId":"5b85712ca3834cdebbbc4363","parentCategoryId":"","parentCategoryName":null}; 
var pageList = {"totalData":549,"totalPage":12,"pageSize":48,"currentPage":1}; 
var pageSize = 48;
</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

script = soup.find("script", text=lambda t: t and "totalPage" in t)
print(re.search(r"totalPage\D+(\d+)", script.text).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
12
```

---

#### 2. Using [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/)

```py
import js2py

script = soup.find("script", text=lambda t: t and "totalPage" in t)
s = "function $() {" + script.text + " return pageList;}"
print(js2py.eval_js(s)()["totalPage"])
```

Prints:

```
12
```

---

#### 3. Using `re`/`json`

```py
import re
import json

script = soup.find("script", text=lambda t: t and "totalPage" in t)
n = json.loads(re.search(r"pageList = (.*);", script.text).group(1))[
    "totalPage"
]
print(n)
```

Prints:

```
12
```

Comment: Seems you provided all the possible option in Python, :)

Comment: @RahulKP There's also `ast.literal_eval` method - if you want you can post (or some more...) I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Yeah, there could be some options like that (silly). But your answer provides the best options for the question.

Comment: An `ast.literal_eval` approach is going to require first extracting a valid Python literal, which will presumably involve using one of the other approaches anyway. It's also not an appropriate replacement for a JSON parser, since it will not properly handle `null` or lowercase `true` or `false`.

Comment: Hi I've tried the above, for a get request for https://alfagift.id/c/Kebutuhan%20Dapur-5b85712ca3834cdebbbc4363 however it's returning Nonetype is not iterable. Can't figure out why

Comment: @gndps Seems that there are empty `<script>` tags. Try `script = soup.find("script", text=lambda t: t and "totalPage" in t)` The rest should be the same (one of methods mentioned above)